ERROR NG8001: 'courses' is not a known element
I want to preface this with I have read through countless other issues here that seem to be the same as the one I get, but it doesn't seem to work for me at all.
I am using a tutorial to learn. the basics of angular and following the tutor step by step. Somehow I still het an error.
First, I am using Angular 17, and the tutor a much older version. So when creating a new project, I had to use the --no-standalone command to be able to have the same folder structure as the tutorial. This allowed the app.module.ts file to be created.
I have created a new component and defined a selector for it. I have imported it in the app.module.ts file, but the element is not know when I try to use ng serve.
I am creating a new component:
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'courses',
    template: '<h2>Courses</h2>'
})

export class CoursesComponents{
    
}

I have imported and declared this component in the app.module.ts file:
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoursesComponents } from './courses.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CoursesComponents
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

And I am trying to show a very simple message on the landing page, thus the app.component.html is as follows:
<h1>Angular</h1>
<courses></courses>

app.component.ts:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'hello-world';
}

main.ts:
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';


platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

No errors are generated in my editor, but when I use the command ng serve in the CLI, I get error NG8001.
Can anyone direct me towards what I am missing and what I am doing wrong?
Thank you!

@NarenMurali Hello,  I have updated the question with the the code you asked for. Note that I haven't made any changes to these files (I was also not instructed to by the tutorial)

You should edit the question with the code, it'll be easier with the code formatting, also can you add the app-routing.module just in case ?

@ArnaudFlaesch I just updated the main question, I realised it is more readable there. Thank you for the comment though!

@ErinDab everything seems fine, could you share the github repo link?

@NarenMurali I seem to have fixed it. I removed the  element from the html file then used the 'ng serve' command again. This loaded the webpage with just the first line. After it loaded, I added the  element again and it compiled without errors.... I do not understand what the problem was at all

Please make sure the AppComponent component has the standalone: true flag in the decorator.
In Angular 17, you have to also import the component which you want to use in another component.
app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {CoursesComponents} from "./componets/courses/courses.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  imports: [CoursesComponents]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-app';
}

If you are using standalone: true than don't need to declare in app.module.ts file
app.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: []
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {

  }
}

courses.component.ts (Make also courses.component as standalone: true)
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-courses',
  standalone: true,
  template: '<h2>Courses</h2>'
})
export class CoursesComponents {

}

Additionally, you don't need to add it manually to every component when creating one. You can use the command below to add standalone: true by default to your component.
ng generate component example-component --standalone

